# How to transform XML with embedded HTML with embedded XML using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet which I'm using to transform XML to HTML for display. Some of the XML has HTML embedded in it, and I have an XSLT rule for this:

```
<xsl:template match='html|div|span|h1|h2|table'>
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that the output sometimes has XML inside an HTML table, and the rule above just gives me the raw untransformed XML inside the HTML, so my browser just ignores the unrecognised XML tags and displays only the text content of the XML. How can I make it transform the inner XML, but pass on all other HTML as-is?

Comment: Please show an XML document that contains exactly the kind of problem you are describing. Also show an entire, but minimal XSLT stylesheet. Thanks.

Comment: Probably by applying templates instead of copying. Hard to say without knowing exactly **how** you want to transform the "inner" XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which involves copying HTML nodes but then applying templates to the content, using <xsl:copy> instead of <xsl:copy-of>.

My XML looked like this:

```
<foo>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <bar>xyz</bar>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</foo>
```

The XSLT rule I had above copied anything inside the HTML tags I expected to see inside the XML, but that copied the "<bar>xyz</bar>" construct, which the browser displayed as just "xyz".

The solution was to use <xsl:copy> instead of <xsl:copy-of>, to apply it to all unrecognised nodes, and to apply templates inside the node with the following rule:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This way, HTML nodes that are not specifically covered are copied, but their contents are processed by applying any applicable templates.